# How to connect existing Firebase project to existing GCP project?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-signin

We have website that allows Google Sign-In, which is connected to a GCP project (project A).
(Basically our web page gets a token from Google sign-in, passes it to our API, and our API configures a Google Client with project A number then verifies the token received from FE).

Separately, we have an existing mobile app, which has a separate Firebase project (project B), and therefore a GCP project with the same number (B).

We want to add Google Sign-In on the mobile app, and pass the token to the same API used on the web, so that Google Sign-In on both web & mobile will use the same project. How can we connect the mobile Firebase project (B) to the GCP project used on web (A)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you needs [Shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc) configuration for this case.

Shared VPC connects resources from multiple projects.

If you set up shared vpc with project A and B, Resources in project A can use resources in project B as if they exits in same VPC boundary.

So your mobile app(project B) will pass the token to the same API that used on your web service(project A) without any other network configuration, Since they are in same network boundary.

Refer the link i attached above to get detailed information about Shared VPC.